# Python Image Reverse

Tags: python

I am trying to flip an image to the complete opposite (left to right) and cannot seem to figure out the code.  I know how to mirror them half and such, however the complete flip seems to be eluding me. I have this so far:

```
def flip(source):
  width=getWidth(source)/2
  height=getHeight(source)
  for y in range(0,height):
    for x in range(0,width):
      leftPixel=getPixel(source,x,y)
      rightPixel=getPixel(source,width-x-1,y)
      color1=getColor(leftPixel)
      color2=getColor(rightPixel)
      setColor(rightPixel,color1)
      setColor(leftPixel,color2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rightPixel=getPixel(source,width-x-1,y)
```

In this line, `width` should be the full width of the image, not half the width. I recommend moving the `/2` into the inner loop range.

```
width  = getWidth (source)
height = getHeight(source)

for y in range(height):
  for x in range(width / 2):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will take a very long time to run relative to the [ImageOps.mirror()](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imageops.htm#tag-ImageOps.mirror) function of the [Python Imaging Library](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a nice style to use already implemented functions:

[flip left <-> right](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html#numpy.fliplr)

[flip up <-> down](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html#numpy.flipud)